# Can different elliptic curve communicate/encrypt with each other? (e.g. prime256v1 with prime521v1)

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

For me it is unclear if elliptic curves are interchangeable?
Lets say Bob has prime256v1 and Alice has prime521v1 keys. Are they able to communicate with each other in a encrypted way?

Same question is if different origin elliptic curves can communicate with each other. Means can primve256v1 communicate with brainpoolP521t1?

Afaik it shall be able able for the key agreement in the diffie hellman sequence, since the derived key can be created by a scalar product from the shared public keys. But the initial part, there both sides agree for a algorithm is unclear. Do they interchange the elliptic curves on starting point? If so how?

Is there any good code example e.g. for java to implement such a approach?

Comment: The short answer is no. There may some instances of them unintentionally forming a group, but in general no. (Your example should probably use domain parameters that are more similar, like the same order of the curve and subgroup order).

Comment: so to use ECC you have to use always a predefined set of elliptic curves along with the domain params?
Does this not make the encryption pretty hard to publish if both alice has a key with prime256v1 and bob has brainpoolP521t1. Do not get the intention of this hard reduction for the communication.

Comment: Yes, the client and server need to use the same curve. Client and server need to know in advance or the protocol needs to allow them to agree on a curve. If the curve is dynamic and can be selected at runtime, then the protocol messages used to select the curve are usually digested and used in the key agreement protocol to detect tampering by MitM.

Comment: Also, a curve is defined by its domain parameters. In the case of prime fields the domain parameters are `{p,a,b,n,G,h}`. Sometimes the parameters are well known and given a name like `prime256v1`. By the way, `prime256v1` is `secp256r1` - same params but different names. `secp256r1` it is *not* equal to `secp256k1`. `r1` is "random", and `k1` is "koblitz". Though the curves are similar you will not agree on a shared secret using them.

Answer (score 1):

The ECDH formula is `shared_coordinate = your_private_coefficient * their_public_coordinate`. If the two parties are using different curves their public coordinates are mutually meaningless.

Alice logically ends up at `dAlice * dBob * GBob` and Bob ends up at `dBob * dAlice * GAlice`. Algebraically, these are only the same when `GAlice == GBob`.

While two curves might be constructed to have G in common with different other parameters, the math won’t work out because without the a/b/n/{p|m,f(x)} parameters matching the two parties aren’t using the same definition of addition/multiplication, and the symbols above become meaningless.